# whereNotExists Laravel cargar datos despues de 6 min

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

al que pueda ayudarme a optimizar la consulta le agradecería, llevo tiempo realizando unas migraciones en un sistema de laravel en mi tiempo cuando apenas entendía lo que era un modelo, vista, controlador.

Anteriormente esta consulta estaba así:

```
 $query_sii_sin_contab = "SELECT *
                FROM venta_sii cs
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 0
                    FROM `venta_contabilidad` cc
                    WHERE cc.cliente_id = cs.cliente_id
                    AND cs.ano = cc.ano
                    AND cs.mes = cc.mes
                    AND cs.rut = cc.rut
                    AND cs.tipo_doc = cc.tipo_doc
                    AND cs.folio = cc.folio
                )
                AND cs.mes = $mes
                AND cs.ano = $ano
                AND cs.cliente_id = $cliente_id
                ";
        $sii_sin_contab = DB::select( DB::raw($query_sii_sin_contab) );
```

Esta consulta tarda una eternidad en cargarse así que decidí usar eloquent dejándola de esta manera:

```
LibroVentaSII::query()->where('mes', $mes)
            ->where('ano', $ano)
            ->where('cliente_id', $cliente_id)
            ->whereNotExists(function($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(0))
                    ->from('venta_contabilidad')
                    ->whereRaw('venta_contabilidad.cliente_id = venta_sii.cliente_id')
                    ->whereRaw('venta_sii.ano = venta_contabilidad.ano')
                    ->whereRaw('venta_sii.mes = venta_contabilidad.mes')
                    ->whereRaw('venta_sii.rut = venta_contabilidad.rut')
                    ->whereRaw('venta_sii.tipo_doc = venta_contabilidad.tipo_doc')
                    ->whereRaw('venta_sii.folio = venta_contabilidad.folio');
            })->get()
```

Sin embargo dicha consulta aun tarda en cargar mas de 3 minutos, quiero ideas o ayuda para llegar al menor tiempo posible cuando se realice dicha consulta.

Dejando claro que las tablas no se relacionan

Answer (score 2):

Para quien le sirva el query de arriba la idea era traer de la tabla `venta_sii`
los registro no encontrados en `venta_contabilidad` dichos registros en esta tabla era cientos de ellos un total de **540.000** regitros lo cual tardaba entre 4 a 6 minutos en obtener el resultado. Asi que viendo [collect](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherenotin) de laravel pude rehacerme la lógica de esta manera

Busco los libros en venta_ssi por mes, año y cliente

```
$libroVentaSII =   LibroVentaSII::query()
            ->where('mes', $mes)
            ->where('ano', $ano)
            ->where('cliente_id', $cliente_id)
            ->get();
```

Luego hago un [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) en la tabla `venta_contabilidad` trayéndome solo los contables encontrado en esta tabla y así poder saber que registro están en `venta_ssi` quedando de esta manera

```
 $libroVenta = LibroVenta::query()
            ->select(
                'tipo_doc',
                'folio',
                'rut'
            )
            ->where('mes', $mes)
            ->where('ano', $ano)
            ->where('cliente_id', $cliente_id)
            ->where(function ($query) use($libroVentaSII){
                $query->whereIn('folio', $libroVentaSII->pluck('folio'));
            })
            ->where(function ($query) use($libroVentaSII){
                $query->whereIn('tipo_doc', $libroVentaSII->pluck('tipo_doc'));
            })
            ->where(function ($query) use($libroVentaSII){
                $query->whereIn('rut', $libroVentaSII->pluck('rut'));
            })
            ->get();
```

Teniendo esto en cuenta realice lo siguiente con collect

```
 $filtered = $libroVentaSII->whereNotIn('folio', $libroVenta->pluck('folio'));
```

Aquí la magia me trae solo los que no se encontraron pasando de una carga de **6 min** a solo **10seg.**. Espero les sea de utilidad

Si alguno tiene una mejora los leo